# Keeping MySQL connection open in Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What I'm trying to do is keep the MySQL connection open from Window1(LoginWindow) to Window2(DBAA). So that in the second window I can read and insert data. When I try to insert data I get "Host not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class LoginWindow
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Public Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & server.Text & ";" _
        & "user id=" & username.Text & ";" _
        & "password=" & password.Password & ";" _
        & "database=" & database.Text & ";"
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connection to Database has been opened.")
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
        Dim DBAA As DBAA = New DBAA
        DBAA.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

   //Non Applicable Code

End Class
```

Here is the second window(DBAA) that opens.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql

Public Class DBAA
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Private Sub insert01_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles insert01.Click
        Try
            con.Open()

            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO `test`.`data` (`value1`) " & _
                                "VALUES ('" & data01.Text & "');"
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If result = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Success!")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your second code you defined your connection, but left out your connection information. You need to supply your connection details. You call .Open for the connection but it doesnt have your connection information.

Also dont keep it open, not good practice at all. Your first code you close it which is good, but your second you left out some details.

EDIT...

If you want to pass the connection you can do so iin the constructor...

Make sure you have this in the second class...

```
 Private Property connection As MySqlConnection 
 Public Sub New(ByVal con as MySqlConnection)
    connection = con
 End Sub
```

Now you can use 'connection' where you would like...

Then you pass the current connection in as argument for your second class...

```
    Dim DBAA As DBAA = New DBAA(MysqlConn)
```

Comment: ok I can add  that,  but  how  do I supply  the connection information input from window1 to window2?

Comment: See edit for updated answer. I wouldnt be passing this though, create a function you can call when you need it.